# .NET CORE 3.1 Virtual Directory 404 error

Tags: iis, .net-core

We have a published .NET Core 3.1 website hosted by IIS. The root folder (containing the DLLs) is:
c:\qa\web\

Otherwise we have folders like:

- c:\qa\web\wwwroot\css
- c:\qa\web\wwwroot\js

In IIS we made a virtual directory named "images". The website can be access via http://localhost

We can view individual files without error:

- http://localhost/js/brand.js
- http://localhost/css/main.css

However we get a 404 when trying to view files in the virtual directory:

http://localhost/images/foo.jpg

But if we insert "/wwwroot" in the URL, we see the contents of the virtual directory without issue:

http://localhost/wwwroot/images/foo.jpg

Why do we need "wwwroot/" in the URL? When we run the same website from Visual Studio / IIS Express, we don't need "wwwroot/" in the URL to view /images/foo.jpg

I thought maybe if we set the Virtual Directory alias to "wwwroot/images" it might work, but it doesn't allow for the slash character in the alias.

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information. [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that virtual directory is created at site level.
It looks like it is nested in wwwroot folder.
Try this - right click on site --> Add virtual directory --> Alias: images, Physical path: c:\qa\web\wwwroot. After this you should reach images under http://localhost/images/js/brand.js, http://localhost/images/css/main.css etc.

If it does't help, consider to keep static files in different folder outside the application root folder, and create virtual directory linked to it.

Comment: It was created at the site-level.

Comment: Failed request tracking is a useful way to solve the problem.

Comment: @samwu until you have Windows 11 and no IE11 and can't view the output of FRT :(

Answer (score 0):

For me, the static files are in a virtual directory. I had to add a `web.config` with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```